# is there a processor for creating a network graph in Data Science Studio?

Tags: python, neo4j, networkx, data-science-studio

My data has three columns, each representing a node in a tree (a->b->c) and I was curious if there existed a recipe that helped prepare the data for import into Neo4j, NetworkX, or other equivalent graph/network explorer. Thanks in advance for any insight you have regarding the transformation of tabular data into graph format.

Comment: NetworkX is a framework for graphs, not "ready-to-use" solution, so you have to create your own data loader.

Comment: Could you clarify, (a->b->c) - means that value from column a has a directed edge to value from column b, and b has one to c?

Comment: @SergeySosnin yes that is correct, a more detailed view might look like:
a->b->c
a->c->d
a->c->e
etc...

Comment: @SergeySosnin imagine left column are locations, middle column are managers at each location, and third column are direct reports to those managers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's a simple python script as an example that can do conversation  (if I correctly understand your trouble):

```
import networkx as nx
import string
str = "a,b,c\nd,e,f\nd,k,j"
print str
lines = string.split(str,'\n')
DG=nx.DiGraph()
for line in lines:
    nodes = line.split(",")
    location = nodes[0]
    manager =  nodes[1]
    report =   nodes[2]
    if (location not in DG):
        DG.add_node(location)
    if (manager not in DG):
        DG.add_node(location)    
    if (report not in DG):
        DG.add_node(location)        
    DG.add_edge(location,manager)
    DG.add_edge(manager,report)

print DG.nodes()
print DG.edges()
```

This code converts `str` string to the directed graph.

Comment: First of all, I greatly appreciate your script. Let me make sure I understand it correctly: the str variable should represent the number of columns (nodes) and each row/line represents an edge? So I could use this on a similar tabular dataset that had 25 columns as long as I changed str to equal a,b,c,...y ?

Thanks again, going to try to incorporate this into my script.

Comment: Yes, but while you have only three columns i make it simple:     location = nodes[0] manager =  nodes[1]   report =   nodes[2]. If you want to use 25 columns it's much more practice to create a loop: for node in nodes...